# How to exclude specific class in android gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, release

Need to exclude specific class only on release build variant. Could you please anyone give some pointers on it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle file use:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        main {     //<-- flavour name (usual values are: "main", "release", debug")
            java {
                exclude '**/*_old.java'
                exclude '**/*_new.java'
                exclude '**/*_backup.java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edited:

In **/main/** flavour:

```
class ClassBase {
    
}
```

In **/debug/** flavour:

```
class ClassA extends ClassBase {
    private ClassC mIncriminatedReference;  //<-- ClassC is the incriminated Class you won't
}
```

In **/release/** flavour:

```
class ClassA extends ClassBase {
    /*no reference to ClassC here*/
}
```

then you can use/extend/instantiate ClassA (the right one will be choosen based on current active flavour) without errors when building for Release.

(I know it's tricky but it's the only way without using a custom PreProcessor as "plugin" while building)

Comment: Thanks a lot , it will exclude the class based on the build variants but I'm error from where I accessing the class. For example I have excluded class A but Class A is used by Class B and this will not needed in release mode , since Class A is excluded I'm getting error in Class B like the import statement of Class A is not available. Please give some pointers on it

Comment: I added the way I use to achieve same thing you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution solved my problem.

Comment: Accepting my answer will be appreciated ;)